# Java Methods with enum Implementation

Tags: java, methods, input, enums

[What I am asked to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYPwh.png)

I have attached a picture of the instructions I am given in this past paper I am currently attempting to complete.

I am currently finishing a University practice exam in the run up to my exam in the summer. So far I have finished most of the question paper however I am currently stuck on this part.

I have implemented the interfaces as instructed, and I have also implemented an enum named directions. Where it says "Details for the Walk and Talk methods in the Entertainment Robot class", I'm not sure how to store the input from the user as an enum. My code so far is listed below. I would appreciate any help on this. Many thanks.

```
package Program;

import java.util.Scanner;


public abstract class Robot {

    //instance variables
    protected double EnergyUnitsRequired;
    protected double height;
    protected String manufacturer;
    protected String name;
    protected String purpose;
    protected double weight;
    protected double energy;
    private Directions direction;

    //constructor
    public Robot(String name, double height, double weight, String manufacturer) {
        super();
        this.EnergyUnitsRequired = 0.25;
        this.height = height;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.name = name;
        this.purpose = "The robot's purpose needs to be provided";
        this.weight = weight;
        this.energy = 0.0;
    }

    //accessors & mutators
    public double getEnergyUnitsRequired() {
        return EnergyUnitsRequired;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPurpose() {
        return purpose;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public double getEnergy() {
        return energy;
    }

    public void setEnergyUnitsRequired(double energyUnitsRequired) {
        EnergyUnitsRequired = energyUnitsRequired;
    }

    public void setHeight(double height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPurpose(String purpose) {
        this.purpose = purpose;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public Directions getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }


    public void setDirection(Directions direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    //methods
    public abstract void start();
    public abstract void stop();
    public abstract void doTask();
    public abstract void doTask(Scanner input);

    public void energyConsumption() {
        System.out.println("The robot: " + getName() + " has: " + getEnergy() + " to begin with.");
        double priorEnergy = getEnergy();
        energy = energy - energyRequired(); //the variable energyRequired should be returned from the energyRequired method below this method.
        System.out.println("My energy has depleted by the following amount: " + (priorEnergy - energy) + " units.");
        System.out.println("My energy is now at: " + energy + " units.");
    }

    public double energyRequired() {
        double energyRequired = (EnergyUnitsRequired * weight);
        return energyRequired;
    }

    public void regenerate() {
        energy = getEnergy() + (getWeight() * 2);
        System.out.println("More energy is being generated for the robot.");
        System.out.println("............................");
        System.out.println("I have now got more energy!.");
    }
}

package Program;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class HumanStudyRobot extends Robot {

    //instance variables

    public HumanStudyRobot(String name, double height, double weight, String manufacturer) {
        super(name, height, weight, manufacturer);
        this.energy = 30.0;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("This is a Human Study Robot");
        System.out.println("The robot has started studying.");
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        System.out.println("The robot has finished studying.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doTask() {
    study();
    }

    @Override
    public void doTask(Scanner input) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void study() {
    if (energy >= energyRequired()) {
        energyConsumption();
    }
    else 
        if (energy < energyRequired()) {
            System.out.println("The robot does not have sufficient energy.");
            regenerate();
            System.out.println("................");
            System.out.println("The robot has finished regenerating");
        }
    }


    public String toString() {
        return "I AM A HUMAN STUDY ROBOT : \nThe details of the entertainment robot are below:\n"
                + "Name : " + getName() + "\nWeight: " + getWeight() + "\nHeight: "
                + getHeight() + "\nManufacturer : " + getManufacturer() + "\nPurpose : "
                + getPurpose();
    }

}

package Program;

import java.util.Scanner;

import org.omg.Messaging.SyncScopeHelper;

public class EntertainmentRobot extends Robot {

    //constructor
    public EntertainmentRobot(String name, double height, double weight, String manufacturer) {
        super(name, height, weight, manufacturer);
        this.energy = 10.0;
        this.EnergyUnitsRequired = 0.75;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("This is an Entertainment Robot. \nThe robot has started entertaining.");
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        System.out.println("I have stopped entertaining people.");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
    }

    @Override
    public void doTask(Scanner input) {
        play();
    }


    @Override
    public void doTask() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void talk() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a phrase for me to repeat");
        String phrase = input.nextLine();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You have asked me to say the following phrase : " + phrase);
    }

    public void walk() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Would you like me to walk for you?");
        if (input.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            System.out.println("For how many paces");
            int steps = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Which direction do you want me to walk? (Enter a number between 1 and 4.) ");
            System.out.println("1 - " + Directions.FORWARD);
            System.out.println("2 - " + Directions.BACKWARD);
            System.out.println("3 - " + Directions.LEFT);
            System.out.println("4 - " + Directions.RIGHT);

        }
    }

    public void play () {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean valid = false;
        int selection;
        do {
        System.out.println("How many times would you like to play?");
        while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("That is not a number");
            input.nextLine();
        }
        selection = input.nextInt();
        valid = true;
        } while(!valid);
        for (int i = 1; i < selection + 1; i ++ ) {
            if (getEnergy() >= energyRequired()) {
                energyConsumption();
            } else if (getEnergy() < energyRequired()) {
                System.out.println("------------WHOOPS--------------.");
                System.out.println("I do not have enough energy to play.");
                regenerate();
            }
        }
        input.close();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "---------------------------------\nI AM AN ENTERTAINMENT ROBOT \nThe details of the entertainment robot are below: \n" + 
                "Name : " + getName() +  "\nWeight: " + getWeight() + "\nHeight: " + getHeight() + "\nManufacturer: " + 
                getManufacturer() + "\nPurpose: " + getPurpose() + "\n----------------------------";
    }

}

package Program;

import java.util.Scanner;

public interface Talkable {
    abstract void talk(Scanner input);
}

package Program;

import java.util.Scanner;

public interface Walkable {
    abstract void walk(Scanner input);
}

package Program;

public enum Directions {
    FORWARD,BACKWARD,LEFT,RIGHT;
}
```

Comment: You probably only need a `switch`-statement to translate the entered number to the corresponding enum... But your question is very long, maybe too long for such a simple problem.

Comment: You can use `Directions.values()[<user entered value> -1]`

Comment: why would it be <user entered value> -1?

Comment: @LiamLaverty because `Direction.values()` returns array of `Direction` in ordey they're declared in enum. I. e. `Direction.values()[0]` will be `FORWARD`, `[1]`-- `BACKWARD` etc.

Comment: ok thanks! so I would just use the Directions.values() { input -1) when taking in input from the user?

Comment: yes, sure. I posted a constructor-argument enums as more common (so you can replace numbers by first letters `F`, `B`, or other keys)

Comment: if you get by index, please consider checking input range to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

Store a direction key in enum itself, like:

```
public enum Direction {

    FORWARD(1), BACKWARD(2), LEFT(3), RIGHT(4);

    final int num;  

    Direction(int num) {
       this.num = num;
    }

    static Direction ofNumber(int num) {
       for (Direction d : values())
          if (d.num == num)
              return d;
       return null;
    }
}
```

Then, when a user inputs a number, just call:

```
Direction selected = Direction.ofNumber(number);
```

Comment: When I try to add a key with 1,2,3 and 4 to the enum Directions it gives a lot of errors.

Comment: maybe because of ending `s`? I called it `Direction` as more appropriate.

Comment: no it gives me the error "not defined in constructor" when i try to set up :     Directions(int num) {
       this.num = num;
    }

Comment: well, I've just put this code into IDE, and it compiles fine... Cannot say which exact problem do you face.